# How can I add an element in the navbar menu

Tags: jhipster

I want to add an element in the navbar of a JHipster site.

Is there a command that can generate this element?

Comment: Your question is way too vague:  you don't say which client framework, which version. Stackoverflow.com is not a JHipster forum,  please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, please follow this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-nav-element

Comment: Yes it's a solution but don't forget that you can also simply edit the generated code, it's all yours.

Comment: The ``generator-jhipster-nav-element`` does not work with the current version jhipster7